# Kiel traduki la anglan verbon "harrumph"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Karaketero en angla romano esprimas sian ĉagrenon per ĉi tiu neparola sono. En la angla oni povas uzi "harrumph" aŭ "pshaw" kiel ekkrioj, kiel verbo, kaj kiel substantivo. Ĝi esprimas kaj skeptikecon kaj koleretiĝo.

Ĉu ekzistas simila esperantlingva verbo?

Answer (score 2):

Oni povus traduki tion per [`grumbli`](http://vortaro.net/#grumbli) (kiu pli rilatas [pshaw](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pshaw)).

Leginte la difinon de [harrumph](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harrumph):

- to clear the throat in a pompous way
- to comment disapprovingly

mi rekomendas ankaŭ viziti la jenan paĝon: [Ekkriaj vortetoj kaj sonimitoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/ekkrioj_sonimitoj/index.html) ĉar, eĉ se vi ne trovas unu ĝustan vorteton, vi povas uzi du sinsekve por interjekcie komuniki la senton.

[baf](http://vortaro.net/#baf) povus transdoni la senton, sed pro ritmaj aferoj, kaj ĉar la neparola frazo estas elstara, vi povus voli uzi pli longan, *pezan* tradukon, ekzemple `baf fi!`

La fina elekto dependas de la kunteksto, ĉu vi povus provizi ekzemplojn? La *ĉagreno* menciita de vi aperas en la difino de la vorto kiel rezulto de propono, ideo aŭ ago de iu alia.

Answer (score 2):

Aldone al "grumbli", oni povas tute regule verbigi la ekkrion "baf" kiel "bafi".